# How to use variable session in two php file bakcend

Tags: php, angularjs, session

I'm developing an AngularJs application with PHP backend, I implemented the authentication step, and now I'm trying to display data of authenticated user in another view after authentication.I used session token to display user data in other view but Even if I did what I read in some tutorials about sessions and tokens more than two weeks, I still can't display user data. And I get this error in display.php file: Undefined index: token
Can you help me, please?

**login.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");  

 if(count($data) > 0)  

 { 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->password);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   password= "'.$password.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $token = md5($Email.time()."51395+81519851");
       $query = "UPDATE client SET token = '".$token."' WHERE EmailClient = '".$Email."'";
       mysqli_query($connect , $query);
       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $_SESSION["token"] = $token; 
       $result['message'] ='Logged In';
       $result['email'] =$Email;
       $result['token'] = $token;

       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;
  }

       $result['message'] ='The username or password are incorrect!';

$resultstring = json_encode($result);
$resultstring = str_replace("null",'""',$resultstring);
echo $resultstring;
exit;
}

?>
```

**display.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");  

 $output = array();  
 $query = "SELECT Name,Adresse FROM client WHERE token = '".$_SESSION['token']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output[] = $row;  
      }  
      echo json_encode($output);  
 }  

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me your code is right. I can't see any reason it would not work.
Can you confirm that the first page loaded is login.php and not display.php ? If you load display.php first, the error would make sens as the $_SESSION has not been set before.

Also to avoid this kind of error i suggest you to make a simple test on your $_SESSION such as :

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["token"] = "hello456";
    if(isset($_SESSION["token"]))
    {
            // code logic here
            echo $_SESSION["token"];
    }
    else
    {
            // do something that will set $_SESSION["token"] such as calling login.php
            $_SESSION["token"] = "some string";
    }
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: the login is the first file called before display, because user has to log in and then display data of the user. How can I call login.php or set $_SESSION. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by call login.php . Could you show me the code where you use the files login.php & display.php ? To set a $_SESSION is easy, and just the way you do it, i will edit my code above to show you an example. $_SESSION is actually manipulated as you would do with any php array. Only the variable range is different from a classic array.

Comment: Ok thank you, I edit my code to show how I call the php backend

Comment: I really see no reason for the PHP to bug or fail here ... And i don't know angular JS at all, are you sure you are calling it correctly ? Does it work if you just load the login.php page and then go to the display.php in your web browser (without using any JS). Also you could print or echo the variable you're trying to use, to make sure it is well set (echo $_SESSION['token']; for example) Keep us updated :)

Comment: Yes it works , for example when I put a simple select in display.php file whithout condition, after login , data are displayed and there is no problem. The problem is when I add : WHERE token = '".$_SESSION['token']."', I don't get any data. and the token is working because I can see it getting updated after each login